# How to import PhpStorm formatter in VSCode?

Tags: phpstorm, visual-studio-code

All programmers in the company I work at use PhpStorm and PhpStorm formatter. I prefer using VSCode, which creates a problem, my code is formatted and indented differently.

I like to  use the formatter that exists in PhpStorm, whether by exporting and importing it somehow or by changing the settings of VSCode formatter, or by using an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using **[phpfmt](https://github.com/kokororin/vscode-phpfmt)** extension to format the visual studio code. You may set your own shortcut key for this also. For this go to preference keyboard shortcut and type **phpfmt** and change your shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

there is the extension vscode code which might help you 
PHPStorm Formatter

[click here to get the vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=animus-coop.vscode-phpstorm-formatter)